# containment operator(@>) in spring data jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

I was going through https://medium.com/hackernoon/how-to-query-jsonb-beginner-sheet-cheat-4da3aa5082a3 link , I came acrosss below sql . This sql is flexible enough to allow key and value in json to be dynamic  . we can search whether metadata json has "country" key attribute and value as "Peru"  or not .I do not want to use native query as key attribute may change depending on need . Is there a way to achieve the same in spring data jpa either through ExampleMatcher or criteria or any other way

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE metadata @> '{"country": "Peru"}';
```